# Oxygen XML Eclipse plugin download location

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, oxygenxml

Where can I download the Oxygen XML Eclipse plugin? I'm looking for a full download link, not the update site for use with Eclipse update. I have the following URL for that:

```
http://www.oxygenxml.com/InstData/Eclipse/site.xml
```

Also, is the plugin free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oxygen [download link](http://www.oxygenxml.com/download_oxygenxml_editor.html#Eclipse), Eclipse plugin [download link](http://www.oxygenxml.com/InstData/Editor/Eclipse3.4/com.oxygenxml.editor_12.1.0.v2011012011.zip).

It is not a free plugin.  There is a 30 day free trial (with trial license).

Comment: Hi Can we extend the trail key after using a month ?

Comment: @srinannapa - I wouldn't know. I just mentioned what I found in the website.  You should contact them.